# map.infoWindow marker symbol does not show up in ArcGIS JSAPI 3.14

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I switched my JSAPI version to 3.14 and now, when I have point features selected, the symbol does not show up. It works fine if I only switch back to 3.12. It also works fine for the line features.

Interestingly enough, I could not find any of the samples in which point features are highlighted when popups are used on a point features identify style tool.

Here is the current symbol setup in case it it helps:

```
selColor = new esri.Color([0, 255, 255, 0.6]);  
selLine = new esri.symbol.CartographicLineSymbol(esri.symbol.CartographicLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, selColor, 10, esri.symbol.CartographicLineSymbol.CAP_ROUND, esri.symbol.CartographicLineSymbol.JOIN_ROUND);  
selMarker = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 20, selLine, selColor);  
mainMap.infoWindow.lineSymbol = selLine;  
mainMap.infoWindow.markerSymbol = selMarker;
```

UPDATE: It seems that this is a bug in 3.14, in PopupWindow class (parent of map.infoWindow). The feature to be highlighted (kept in _highlighted member), through the added symbol to the graphics layer or the map does not have its symbol correctly set for point features while it gets set correctly for line features.

Comment: You might get more help if you can provide a complete but brief example of the code you have tried.

Comment: This is pretty much the code, the rest is standard so if someone has worked with ArcGIS JSAPI, they would know what I am talking about. Yet, I will try to add some more code.

Comment: @derekswingley any thoughts?